# When I include files in PHP, it gives me a blank screen?

Tags: php, include, screen

I'm trying to include the header at the top of my pages, but it gives me a blank screen. When I remove it the PHP file runs and shows the content:

```
<?php
    include("header.php");
?>
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is probably an error in that file. try turning display errors and reporting on:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Escaped my mind, but does this work if `header.php` has a parse error?

Comment: thanks, how can i turn on the errors globally, and i fixed the problem. thanks

Comment: @boltclock: as long as he does it before the include statement i think so... but im not 100% on that.

Comment: @getaway in your php.ini file, but you might not want to do that if the site is "live"

Comment: @getaway: Heed hookedonwinter's warning.

Comment: im just testing it, im on a dedciated server, i cnt seem to find my php.ini file, im using plesk.

Comment: `php --ini` from the shell will give you the location of the CLI ini file. normally they will both be in the directory unless youve set CLI up to use one in your `$HOME`. convention generally puts them in `/etc`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using "include" and not "require", the white screen means you have an error in header.php itself.  Use error reporting to narrow the issue down and fix the root of the problem.